# Output of fetched data to a variable as an Int

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In this example, print gewicht gives an output of optional({10)} i need the output (10) as
an Int assigned to a variable . So the output has to be let mijnGewicht = 10
How can i do that. Iam new to swift, so excuse me for the question.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext = appDelegate!.persistentContainer.viewContext

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Dogs")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "Toni")
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["gewicht"]


do {
    let fetchedResults = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)


    for i in fetchedResults {
        dogs.append(i as! NSManagedObject)




        for i in dogs {

            let gewicht = i.value(forKeyPath: "gewicht.kg")
            print(gewicht)
            }
```

Comment: What is `kg`? It seems to be a collection type. And it's bad practice to use `i` as an *element* variable in multiple nested for loops.

Comment: its core data, The entity is "Dogs", i use predicate to fetch a dog. Then i use relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching to get the values of the relationship "gewicht", KG is an attribute of that relationship, so gewicht.kg

Comment: Off topic but use proper variable names and not single letter ones and don't re-use variable names either. This improves code readability and maintainability

Comment: The question can be answered probably at once if you add the information how the relationship and its attributes is declared in the model. And why do you use unspecified `NSManagedObject` rather than the real subclass?

Comment: The model in core date;  Entity 'Dogs" with atrribute "name"  and an Entity gewicht with atrribute "kg". its a one to many relationship. I want to fetch the KG of specific dog in a variable let mijnGewicht. The output i get is {(
    15,
    10
)} . but i cannot get the 10 or the 15 as an Int

Comment: That is because it is an to-many relationship so you get a collection of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealing with unspecified `NSManagedObject` and `value(forKeypath:` is outdated.

Take advantage of the generic abilities of Core Data. The benefit is no type cast and no `Any`.

First declare `dogs` as

```
var dogs = [Dogs]()
```

By the way it's highly recommended to name entities in singular form. Semantically you have an array of `Dog` instances.

Create the fetch request for the specific `NSManagedObject` subclass `Dogs`
As `gewicht` is a to-many relationship you have to use a loop to get all values

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext = appDelegate!.persistentContainer.viewContext

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Dogs>(entityName: "Dogs")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "Toni")
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

do {
    let result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    dogs.append(contentsOf: result)
    for dog in dogs {
        for gewicht in dog.gewicht {
            let kg = gewicht.kg
            print(kg)
        }
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

If the relationship and/or the attribute is declared optional (which is still unclear) you have to unwrap the optional.

And consider that the integer value is `Int16`, `Int32` or `Int64` (unfortunately this information is missing, too). There is no `Int` type in Core Data.

And it's up to you how to distinguish the *many* values.

Comment: Tx for your answer, but i get an issue at : for gewicht in dog.gewicht.  For-in loop requires 'NSSet?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?

Comment: Declare the relationship as non-optional native `Set<gewicht>` – and name entities always with starting uppercase letter.

Comment: let kg = gewicht.kg --> changed it to let kg = (gewicht as AnyObject).kg.     And now its working! i get the values. But i dont understand it :)

Comment: Avoid a bridge cast to `AnyObject`, use native types as much as possible.

Comment: Ok sorry, i just can get my head around it, kg in core data is a Double. What can i do to use native type in this code

Comment: As I said replace `NSSet` with `Set<>`

Comment: without the cast to AnyObject i get the error. :  Value of type 'NSSet.Element' (aka 'Any') has no member 'kg'

Comment: Did you read my suggestion? Once again: ***Declare the relationship as non-optional native `Set<gewicht>`*** in `Dogs`

Comment: Ok, thanks man you helped me a lot. Its a tough thing for me core data. But its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this, it checks if the value you are assigning is not nil and then prints it

```
for i in dogs {
     if let mijnGewicht = i.value(forKeyPath: "gewicht.kg"){
          print(mijnGewicht)
     }

}
```

Comment: The output of that is {(10,15)} . I need that 10 assigned as an Int which i can assign to  a variable.

Comment: try `if let mijnGewicht = i.value(forKeyPath: "gewicht.kg").first{
          print(mijnGewicht)
     }` or `if let mijnGewicht = i.value(forKeyPath: "gewicht.kg")[0].first{
          print(mijnGewicht)
     }`

Comment: tx, thats giving me the error :  Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'first'

Comment: `if let mijnGewicht = i.value(forKeyPath: "gewicht.kg")[0]{ print(mijnGewicht) } ` Have you tried this one?

Comment: yeah, error :  Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts

Comment: Ok, then try down casting your value `if let mijnGewicht = i.value(forKeyPath: "gewicht.kg") as? [Int]{
          print(mijnGewicht[0])
     }`

Comment: Thats giving me no Output, so no 10

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    let gewicht = i.value(forKeyPath: "gewicht.kg")
     if let gewichtInt = gewicht as? Int {
         print(gewichtInt)
     }
```

Comment: No result on the print statement.
I dont understand the output in my own code its ({10,15)} the if let statements are not giving any results.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in dogs {
    if let gewicht = i.value(forKeyPath: "gewicht.kg") {
       print(gewicht) // this will give you the safe value as Int, if the value is nill it will not come in this if condition
    }
    let x = i.value(forKeyPath: "gewicht.kg") ?? 0
    print (x) //this will give you wrapped safe value of gewicht.kg if exists else it will give you 0
}
```

here in above example i have shown you two ways to safe cast a value from optional, you can also use guard or guard let on the basis of your requirement

Comment: The output of your code is. {(
    15,
    10
)}. is want that 10 as an Int assigned to a new variable.